# Finding the operator norm in $l^{p}$

Tags: functional-analysis

We have the mapping $T: (l^p, \|\cdot\|) \rightarrow (l^p, \|\cdot\|)$, and $x \in l^\infty $ with the formula $ T(y) = xy $. I have shown that $\|T\| \leq \|x\|_{\infty}$. I am trying to prove that $\|T\| \geq \|x\|_{\infty}$ by using the definition $\|T\| = \sup\{\|T(x)\|, \|x\| \leq 1\}$, and I am considering sequences in $l^p$ such as $1/n^2$, $\sin(\frac{1}{n^{2}})$, etc., but I'm stuck. How can we prove that $\|T\| \geq \|x\|_{\infty}$?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\|x\|_\infty := \sup_{i\in\mathbb N} |x_i| $, so for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $i_0\equiv i_0(\varepsilon)$ such that $|x_{i_0}|> \|x\|_{\infty}-\varepsilon $.

Hence if you consider the sequence $y:= (\delta_{i,i_0})_{n\in\mathbb N} \in\ell^p$ (where $\delta$ is a [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), so here $y_i = 1$ if $i=i_0$ and $0$ otherwise), you have that $\|y\|=1 $ and $\|Ty\| = |x_{i_0}| > \|x\|_{\infty} -\varepsilon$

By that reasoning you can construct a sequence $y_1,y_2,\ldots$ of elements of $\ell^p$ with norm $1$ such that for all natural numbers $k$, $\|Ty_k\| > \|x\|_{\infty} -1/k$.

Now you should be able to finish.

Comment: Thank you very much! How did you come up with the idea for the Kronecker function? As for finding the norm of an operator, I know that we need to use the definition for $\leq$  and the proposition that uses the supremum for $\geq$. However, I often get stuck with the supremum.

Comment: you're welcome ! My first thought when reading the question was to take a sequence $y^*$ which is $0$ everywhere and $1$ at the index where $x$ reaches its supremum, since this would immediately give $\|Ty^*\| = \|x\|_\infty $. But I know the supremum is not necessarily attained so instead I created a sequence of $y_k$'s which "almost" reach it.